# How to fix Visual Studio debugger watch window showing decompiled values

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have recently installed the RTM version of VS 2012, and when I run the debugger the watch window gives me what appears to be a decompiled vision of the local values.  My initial thought was that I accidently hit the "Hexadecimal" display, but that is not the case.  When I try to look at sub-properties off a given object, I get nothing, not even a representation if the object is null.

I won't know exactly what I may have set that is causing this, but VS 2010 did not do this, and the first day with VS2012RTM also didn't do this. I'm reasonably certain this is a setting I clicked, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

Here are a couple screen shots of what the watch window looks like, and my debugging settings.  As an aside, I have tried resetting my settings to factory, and turning IntelliTrace on and off.

[image: Watch Window][image: Debugger settings 1][image: Debugger settings 2]

Comment: I have the same issue. Watch window works perfectly for console applications, but when I try to connect to w3wp running - watch window won't work. Not sure if that is a config setting, since it never worked for me in VS2012. Although VS2010 still works perfectly on a same machine.